# Looking for a third-party diagnostic application for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, diagnostics

I am looking for a good third-party diagnostic application capable of diagnosing Bluescreen and registry issues for Microsoft Windows 10.

After the last update, I have a few workstations that are throwing Bluescreens every 5 to 10 minutes.  The Windows Bluescreen Troubleshooter reports no issues.